# Angular universal web config file with ssl and www redirecting

Tags: html, angular, typescript, iis, web-config

I have a little problem with the web.config file of my angular universal project. My web.config file is like this;

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a node.js application
        to be handled by the iisnode module -->

        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="sendToNode">
                    <match url="/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

We are trying to add a www redirecting when there is no www written into link and a https redirecting when there is no https written in the url. But we couldnt manage to do this.

Should I need to do something from the Angular for this?

How can we add those two redirectings into our angular universal web config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000"/>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the main.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
        </rule>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^main.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <match url="^(?!.*login).*$"></match>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!-- Restart the server if any of these files change -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;browser/*.*" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this really worked man. Thank you a lot, you have saved my life!